# How to use touchpad gestures to scroll back and forth in history on non-Mac OSX devices in Google Chrome?

Tags: linux, macos, google-chrome, touchpad

I prefer the way how Mac OS X allows users to use touchpad gestures to scroll back and forth in the tab history of Google Chrome. Is it possible to use similar touchpad gestures on non-Mac OS X devices, particularly laptops running Google Chrome on Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a truely touchpad gesture recognition but a mouse recognition, you can give a try to [easystroke](https://github.com/thjaeger/easystroke/wiki)

> Easystroke is a gesture-recognition application for X11. Gestures or strokes are movements that you make with you mouse (or your pen, finger etc.) while holding down a specific mouse button. Easystroke will execute certain actions if it recognizes the stroke; currently easystroke can emulate key presses, execute shell commands, hold down modifiers and emulate a scroll wheel.

I use it a lot in chrome to manage :

- navigation through tabs with left / right movements,
- navigation in history with up / down movements,
- closing windows with diagonal left down movement,
- reopening last closed tab with diagonal up movement

### This is only some examples you can configure as much actions and moves you want of course

As requested, a screenshot (in French) of my configuration that I use on Ubuntu (as configuration is not easily exportable). Nothing exceptionnal, the only interessant trick is the use of a top level folder where you define your gestures. Doing so, you can share the same configuration across applications or applications derivates (main use, chrome web applications that are not recognized by easystroke as chrome).

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is the functionality of Easystroke comparable to extensions such as [smartUp Gestures](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bgjfekefhjemchdeigphccilhncnjldn)? With these extensions I can perform gestures upon right touchpad click. My idea was not having to press a button at all.

Comment: Yes this is similar but works in any program not only the web browser. However, it doesn't support multitouch capabilities, so you need to hold a key to enter in gesture recognition. I agree that it's less ergonomic that multitouch gestures for trackpad users but it works better for trackpoint and mouse users :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right! Pressing any other button that the right touchpad button sounds convenient! Is it possible for you to share your config for the Chrome-related part?

Comment: Just added a screenshot of my config, nothing exceptionnal. And sorry, it's in french :)

Comment: Could you tell me how I can record a gesture?